# Why is java still printing even after java vm has been terminated?

Tags: java

I'm working on a simple compiler. When an error is present in the code my compiler needs to throw an error and terminate. However, when my error code is printed and the Java VM is terminated I'm still getting output from the program.

To print the error and terminate I'm using:

```
System.err.println("Line....)
System.err.println("insert message here");
System.exit(0);
```

This is my output when I run the program in eclipse (not desired):

```
Enter an integer number for variable p
4

Line 5, d = c * d
error: variable c has not been defined

20
```

This is my output when it's run through the debugger in eclipse (this is desired):

```
Enter an integer number for variable p
4

20

Line 5, d = c * d
error: variable c has not been defined
```

I've checked through my program multiple times and everything seems to be correct, guess that might be apparent since it runs correctly in the debugger.

Here is the code I'm inputting into my compiler, variable c in line 5 has not yet been declared thus should result in an error. However, the output for variable d should be printed before the error (like the debugger):

```
read p
q = 2
d = p * p + q * q
print d
d = c * d
print d
```

I wasn't completely comfortably uploading my code since this is part of a class assignment and I don't want anyone submitting it.

I found if you run this bit of code, the problem appears if run enough times:

```
public class OutputError {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.err.println("System err");
            System.out.println("System out");
        }
    }
}
```

From the code above I had gotten an output of (after running twice):

```
System err

System out

System err
System err
System err
System errSystem out

System out

System out

System out


System err
System out

System err
System out

System err
System out

System err
System out

System err
System out
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to include a small but complete program that demonstrates the problem. It's fine if the stripped down program isn't particularly useful. As long as it demonstrates the problem, that's enough. Consider hardcoding user input, or replacing function calls with canned results.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thanks for the reply and edit. I'll try to include an example next time, but an answer has already solved my issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool, sounds good. For what it's worth, creating a minimal reproducible example not only helps get good answers here, it's also a great debugging technique. When you have hundreds of lines of code you may be fuzzy about what's going on. I've found that stripping my code down to the bare minimum brings clarity. It's pretty easy when you only have 5 or 10 lines of code to see where the problem lies. I can't tell you how many times the very act of creating an MRE for a question has led me to the solution and let me skip posting altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are writing the numbers to System.out.

If you write things into different streams (out and err), there is no guarantee in which order they will show up in your terminal / console.

I can assure you that your program does not actually *write* things after terminating, but there is some delay between your program sending something into the output streams and it actually showing up, which is the reason why your output is a bit shuffled around in your example.

To test this, put all your stuff into System.out and they should show up in the correct order.